# Existence of Untouchable Betrothed Numbers

Tags: number-theory

An **untouchable number** is a positive integer that cannot be expressed as the sum of all the proper divisors of any positive integer (including the untouchable number itself). The first few untouchable numbers are: $2, 5, 52, 88, 96, 120, 124, 146, 162, 188, 206, 210, 216, 238, 246, 248, 262, 268, 276, 288, 290.$

**Betrothed numbers** or **quasi-amicable numbers** are two positive integers such that the sum of the proper divisors of either number is one more than the value of the other number.
The first few pairs of betrothed numbers are: $(48, 75), (140, 195), (1050, 1925), (1575, 1648), (2024, 2295), (5775, 6128).$

Do numbers exist that are both untouchable and betrothed? And if they do what is the condition of their existence?

Comment: $8892$ is untouchable and is betrothed to $16587$.  (I have no idea about the second part of the question; this was found by a search through the list of [untouchable](http://oeis.org/A005114/b005114.txt) and [betrothed](http://oeis.org/A005276/b005276.txt) numbers at the OEIS.)

Comment: Well that's that for the first part.